# Centering section title in new environment

Tags: pdftex, environments, cv

I have defined a new environment for the sections for a CV template. I'm not sure how to center the section title in this code.

```
    \newenvironment{rSection}[1] 
    { 
    
    % 1 input argument - section name
        
        \sectionskip
        
        \begingroup
        
        \colorbox{mygrey} 
    {
        
        {\rlap{\MakeUppercase{\bf #1}}\hspace{\linewidth}\hspace{-2\fboxsep}}
        
         }
        
        \endgroup
        
        \begin{list}{} { \setlength{\leftmargin}{0 em} } \item[] } { \end{list}
        
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to use center environment like this:

```
\begin{center}
  Section title
\end{center}
```

or the command centering like this :

```
\begingroup
\centering
\colorbox{mygrey} 
{

{\rlap{\MakeUppercase{\bf #1}}\hspace{\linewidth}\hspace{-2\fboxsep}}

Section title }
....
....
```